# .htaccess rewrite every request to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using `.htaccess` for the first time and I'm encountering a loop problem. I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. `http://something.com` rewrites to `http://something.com/main`
2. `http://something.com/anything` rewrites to `http://something.com/index.php?page=anything`

So far my current attempt looks like this, which works satisfactorily:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?$ /main [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

However, I would like to remove both rewrite conditions to also allow requests to `http://something.com/index.php` to become `http://something.com/index.php?page=index.php`. Removing the two `RewriteCond` lines results in a loop and the rewrite doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove those conditions but you would need to reverse your rules and remove leading `/` from target URIs:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ main [L]
```

Also remember that now your first rule will also rewrite css/js/image requests to `index.php?page=...`. If you want to avoid that then add this condition before first `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
```

Comment: Thank you! This works exactly as I want it to. The rewrite is for a web app, which dynamically loads content from an external CDN. Intended behavior is for everything to go through `index.php` in this case.